# Real $3 \times 3$ matrix such that $A^{3} = Id$ and minimal polynomial $x^{2} + x + 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a $3 \times 3$ real matrix $A$ such that it has a minimal polynomial $x^{2} + x + 1$ and is such that $A^{3} = Id$? If so, what an example of such a matrix?

My thought is that the answer is no since the invariant factors of $A$ must divide $x^{2} + x + 1$ which does not split over $\mathbb{R}$. Thus $A$ does not have a rational canonical form over $\mathbb{R}$ and hence no such $A$ exists. However, I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: If $A^3=1$, then $A$ satisfies $x^3-1=0$. In fact, this must be its characteristic polynomial since it is degree $3$. Notice that $(x^2+x+1)(x-1)=x^3-1$. Can you conclude that such a matrix can exist?

Answer (score 5):

The irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomial are precisely those of the minimal polynomial. Since the latter in this case has exactly one such factor, which is moreover of degree two, we see that the degree of the characteristic polynomial is even.

Since $3$ is not even, there can be no such matrix.